# Grape version issue

Tags: ruby, rack, ruby-grape

I have two simple API classes:

```
class API::Root < Grape::API
    version 'v1', :using => :path

    mount API::Appointments => '/appointments'
end
```

and

```
class API::Appointments < API::Base
    get do
    end 
end
```

The issue is that `API::Appointments` generates route:

```
GET        /appointments/v1
```

as opposed to

```
GET        /v1/appointments
```

Is this how it's suppose to be? What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't version path component be before any other path component as oppose to in the end?

Thanks

Comment: Even though you're mounting the Appointments API inside API::Root, it's not inheriting the versioning strategy from it. The first route might be responding for the method - get ":id" do - from API::Appointments.

Answer (score 2):

From the example you gave, your resource file (appointments) is inheriting from the root.rb file, which uses a `:path` to get the version. Additionally, you are mounting to a path by using `mount API::Appointments => '/appointments'`, this acts much like a prefix and thus will prefix your routes with `/appointments`, so the routes you are seeing are expected given your set up. When I version a JSON api using Grape, I have a base root.rb class which will mount my versioned APIs.

```
module API
  class Root < Grape::API
    mount API::V1::Root
  end
end
```

Then for each additional API version, I have another root.rb file which then mounts the resource files for that particular API.

```
module API
  module V1
    class Root < Grape::API
      version 'v1' using: :path
      mount API::V1::Appointments
    end
  end
end
```

With this structure you can have a resource class

```
module API
  module V1
    class Appointments < Grape::API
      get do
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

and it will be mounted to the route `/v1/appointments`